# common-lisp — how to wrap a built-in function that has var-args?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, variadic-functions

I’d like to wrap the built-in:

```
     (concatenate ‘string <arg1> <arg2> .. <argn>)
```

To be something like this:

```
     (strcat <arg1> <arg2> ... <argn>)
```

The issue is - how to do var-args in common-lisp?  I see two possible paths:

1. accept a list as a parameter, then `splat` it / `apply` it [neither of which I know either]
2. var-args special syntax in common-lisp?  `ex: ...`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun strcat (&rest args)
  (apply #'concatenate 'string args))
```